# How to Expose OpenStack Instances to Local Host Physical Network?

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I've deployed OpenStack via DevStack on an Ubuntu server (IP: 192.168.1.9). I'm seeking guidance on exposing OpenStack instances to my local network (IP range: 192.168.1.x). How can I configure OpenStack to allow instances to be accessed from my host machine using local network IPs without encountering conflicts? Any insights would be appreciated.

I've deployed OpenStack via DevStack on an Ubuntu server (IP: 192.168.1.9). I'm seeking guidance on exposing OpenStack instances to my local network (IP range: 192.168.1.x).